# Truffle test fails with Error: Could not find artifacts

Tags: solidity, truffle

I learn the demo: Code is come from: https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop, when I test:

```
$ truffle.cmd test
Using network 'development'.

Compiling .\test\TestAdoption.sol...


TestAdoption
1) "before all" hook: prepare suite


0 passing (30s)
1 failing

1) TestAdoption
   "before all" hook: prepare suite:
Error: Could not find artifacts for /E/blockchain/pet-            
shop/contracts/Adoption.sol from any sources
at Resolver.require (D:\nvm\v10.14.2\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-resolver\index.js:37:1)
  at TestResolver.require (D:\nvm\v10.14.2\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\lib\testing\testresolver.js:17:1)
  at TestResolver.require (D:\nvm\v10.14.2\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\lib\testing\testresolver.js:17:1)
  at dependency_paths.forEach.dependency_path (D:\nvm\v10.14.2\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\lib\testing\soliditytest.js:203:1)
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at deployer.deploy.then (D:\nvm\v10.14.2\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\lib\testing\soliditytest.js:202:1)
  at D:\nvm\v10.14.2\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-deployer\src\deferredchain.js:20:1
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I updated my nodejs lastest, and installed window-build-tools,it does not work.

TestAdoption.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/Adoption.sol";

contract TestAdoption {
    Adoption adoption = Adoption(DeployedAddresses.Adoption());
    function testUserCanAdoptPet() public {
        uint returnedId = adoption.adopt(expectedPetId);

        Assert.equal(returnedId, expectedPetId);
    }
    uint expectedPetId = 8;

    address expectedAdopter = address(this);
    function testGetAdopterAddressByPetId() public {
        address adopter = adoption.adopters(expectedPetId);
        Assert.equal(adopter, expectedAdopter, "Owner of the expected pet should be this contract");
    }

    function testGetAdopterAddressByPetIdInArray() public {
        address[16] memory adopters = adoption.getAdopters();
        Assert.equal(adopters[expectedPetId], expectedAdopter, "Owner of the expected pet should be this contract");
    }    

}
```

2_deploy_contracts.sol:

```
var Adoption = artifacts.require("Adoption");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(Adoption);
};
```

And `import "truffle/Assert.sol";` vscode say: Source "truffle/Assert.sol" not found: File import callback not supported.My friend's version is 0.4.14 and work well, may be a version problem?

[image]

Here is project dir(just a demo from https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop):

[image]

Comment: Open your text editor, expand all folders and show us all folders and files you have. Probably this is just wrong import paths problem.

Comment: If you try this on ubuntu or mac your test will be past, is a bug of truffle 5 on windows. They will fix it in other version.

Comment: @Belen Martin can you link to the issue please?

Comment: I think this might be it https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/1630

Answer (score 0):

This error DOESN'T happen (currently) in the version **v5.1.10** of truffle.

My full error was:

```
TypeError: Error parsing C:/Users/PATH/yourSmartContract.sol: Cannot destructure property 'body' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.
```

**My solution is to downgrade the version like so:**

1. `$ npm uninstall -g truffle`
2. `$ npm install -g truffle@v5.1.10`

(Developing in BC is hard because of version control and managment. Keep the good the work.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the name of the artifact is defined according to the contract's name. This is your contract:

```
contract TestAdoption {

}
```

So;

2_deploy_contracts.sol:

```
// not artifactsrequire(Adoption)
var Adoption = artifacts.require("TestAdoption");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(Adoption);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these files:

1_initial_migration.js:

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

2_deploy_contracts.js:

```
const YourContractName = artifacts.require("YourContractName");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(YourContractName);
};
```

Tips:

- **Do not** change the name of the files (1_initial_migration.js and 2_deploy_contracts.js);
- Use the **exactly** name of your contract in the "2_deploy_contracts" file (if it is called BatatinhaFrita123, you need to specify BatatinhaFrita123 inside the artifacts.require()).